# Address Verification Failure - Error Message (Authorize.net) - Server Error

Tags: magento2

When a customer checks out on my Magento 2 website, and the credit card is rejected due to an AVS mismatch (Authorize.net), Magento 2 only says "server error". Where can I edit this to say "Address verification failure"?

On Magento 1, I was able to install a plugin that allowed for Authorize.net to provide customers with custom messages. This is not available for Magento 2, so I would just like to change "server error" to "address verification failure" so the customers know that is why their order did not go through.

Answer (score 0):

the workaround I put into place:

Copy

```
`vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/transparent/iframe.phtm1`
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[THEME]/Magento_Payment/templates/transparent/iframe.phtml.
```

Edit the new template's

block, especially the message: $t('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.') line. This block checks if there is an error message, but never actually uses it. I changed the text to:

```
if ($msg === 'This transaction has been declined.') {
    $msg = 'The transaction was declined. Please review your payment details and try again.';
}
```

This block alters the error a bit, to make it more customer friendly.